# How to allow sites to play protected content in electron desktop app

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, electron

I have an LMS its videos playing perfect on chrome and firefox browser but getting this on electron app:

```
Please ALLOW from Chrome settings > Site settings > Protected Content.
```

I don't know how to enable protected content in my electron app there is nothing in there API documentation.

Comment: Here is the code repository: https://github.com/huzoorbux/electron-quick-start

Answer (score 0):

You can look at to this document for solving problem.
https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/testing-widevine-cdm